# java Generics - How to call child overloaded method knowing the child class type and the superclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a bunch of classes that extend a base class. The base class has a method shall we say :

```
doStuff1(int variable){ do something;}
```

Each of these classes have a :

```
doStuff1(String string) {convert string to number and call super.doStuff1(intResult)};
```

In another class, method I have something like:

```
public void bla(Class<?> childClass, SuperClass childClassInDisguise) {
    (childClass.cast(childClassInDisguise)).doStuff1(myString);
}
```

I cannot compile this because of:
The method doStuff1(myString) is undefined for the type capture#17-of ?

What am I doing wrong here ?
Is this even possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: (maybe unrelated) If you are going to implement it on every child class, why don't you make it abstract?

Also: I have never seen that kind of cast (not saying it doesn't work); why not use the classic `((SuperClass) childInDisguise).doStuff1(myString);` ?

Comment: Is `doStuff1(String)` a method of the base class?

Comment: ```(childClass.cast(childClassInDisguise))``` returns an object not SuperClass. Change to ```void blah(Class<? extends SuperClass>```

Comment: @Joseph it won't work, it says:
is not applicable for the arguments String

Comment: Why can't you just convert from string to int in the bla method and then call doStuff1 in the base class? No casting required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler don't know which class this represents to,

```
Class<?>
```

and the only clue it knows with regards to the object is that it has a superclass which only have doStuff1(int)

If you really want to call the doStuff1(String), why not create another abstract subclass that contains this method and marked this method as abstract. The existing subclasses should extend this new subclass.

```
public abstract class NewSubclass extends Superclass {
  public void abstract doStuff1(String);
}
```

Then in your method, add a generic parameter such as

```
    public <T extends NewSubclass>void bla(Class<T> childClass, SuperClass childClassInDisguise) {
        (childClass.cast(childClassInDisguise)).doStuff1(myString); 
    }
```

This way, the compiler knows the inheritance heirarchy of the object which are subclasses of the NewSubclass that contains that abstract method.

**EDIT**

If you can only edit bla method, try this,

```
public void bla(Class<?> childClass, SuperClass childClassInDisguise) {
      if(childClass.equals(ChildClass1.class) {
        (ChildClass1(childClassInDisguise)).doStuff1(myString);
     } else ... {
     } 
}
```

Do the same if condition in other known subclasses. I know its hardcoded, but this is the only way if you can't use generic + abstract superclass by modifying those classes involved. But I still prefer my first suggestion since its less code and dynamic,  like when you add another subclass, you don't have to change bla method again(the power of POLYMORPHISM), unlike the second suggestion. This is more of a design reconstruction issue.

Comment: is there another way ? because it seems I can't do the suggested modification.

Comment: yes there is, you can try to use a strategy pattern where in using instanceof on childClass if it is matches any of the subclasses with doStuff1, but this is sort of hard coded. But which code can you directly modify?

Comment: I can only modify the code that contains the method bla.